# Generate a card with random images

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have a website where I have cards that have images. I have named the images "wp1", "wp2" and so on. I want the  src to have wp(number).png generated on random.

```
<div class="mainWallpapersPanel">
<div class="wallpaperCard">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/wp18.png" alt="" class="wallpaperIMG"></a>
          <h4><a href="#" class="downloadLink">download</a></h4>
        </div>
</div>
```

Above is the card which I have created using div. The main div is "mainWallpapersPanel". I want there to be 18 of these cards in the main div with image src to have the wp no. generated randomly.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to generate a random number using HTML alone.You will need to reference a ***JavaScript*** script ([guide on how to reference JS in HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_scripts.asp)).

You can use [Math.random()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_random.asp) with [Math.floor()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) to generate integer numbers.

Here is the MDN documentation for `Math.Random()`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random